# Place a sidewaysfigure correctly in a two column document

Tags: rotating, sidewaysfigure

I am having a problem with the alignment of my figures and text and I have attempted to create a minimal working example to illustrate the problem. Apologies that it is text heavy but I needed to add lots of text to get my problem to appear.

I am using:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
```

and

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[ht]
```

To rotate my figures by 90 degrees. When I do this, My figures are not central on the page and they are trying to fit into a two column format and so end up pushed towards the left hand side of the page. I am told that this is because the default format for apj is twocolumn.

In order to fix this, I just put:

```
\onecolumngrid
```

before the figures and:

```
\twocolumngrid
```

after. This fixes my problem with the figures, but it also has the effect of messing up my text. if you convert my tex into a pdf, on page 2 you will see something like the following:

[image]

you see that the first left hand column stops about half way down the page and then continues in the right hand column instead of continuing to the bottom of the page? In other words the top two paragraphs are a pair and the bottom two are a pair.

This is obviously a result of me turning the \onecolumngrid on and off. But how can I get my figures to plot correctly (centrally on a one column page) and not have my text mess up?

Thank you!

```
\documentclass{emulateapj}
\newcommand{\vdag}{(v)^\dagger}
\newcommand\aastex{AAS\TeX}
\newcommand\latex{La\TeX}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,etoolbox}
%\usepackage{longtable}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
%\usepackage{float}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{caption}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\title{MINIMAL WORKING EXAMPLE}

\author{
  A.~N.~Other\altaffilmark{1},
  A.~N.~Other\altaffilmark{1},
  A.~N.~Other\altaffilmark{1},
  A.~N.~Other\altaffilmark{1},
  A.~N.~Other\altaffilmark{1}}

\affil{$^{1}$Department of Blah, Blah University}

\begin{abstract}
abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve.

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve.

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve.

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve.

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve.

\onecolumngrid
\begin{center}
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{fig2a.png} &
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{fig2b.png}
  \end{tabular}
    \captionof{figure}{Figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption.}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{fig3a.png} &
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{fig3b.png}
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{figure}{Figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption.}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
\end{center}
\twocolumngird

\onecolumngrid
\begin{center}
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{fig4a.png} &
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{fig4b.png}
  \end{tabular}
      \captionof{figure}{Figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption.}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{fig5a.png} &
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{fig5b.png}
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{figure}{Figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption.}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
\end{center}
\twocolumngrid

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure* still works.  One can emulate `sidewaysfigure` with a `minipage` and `\rotatebox` (graphicx package).

```
\documentclass{emulateapj}
\newcommand{\vdag}{(v)^\dagger}
\newcommand\aastex{AAS\TeX}
\newcommand\latex{La\TeX}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,etoolbox}
%\usepackage{longtable}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
%\usepackage{float}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{caption} 

%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{MINIMAL WORKING EXAMPLE}

\author{
  A.~N.~Other\altaffilmark{1},
  A.~N.~Other\altaffilmark{1},
  A.~N.~Other\altaffilmark{1},
  A.~N.~Other\altaffilmark{1},
  A.~N.~Other\altaffilmark{1}}

\affil{$^{1}$Department of Blah, Blah University}

\begin{abstract}
abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve.

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve.

\begin{figure*}[p]
  \sbox0{\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=110mm]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=110mm]{example-image-b}
  \end{tabular}}% measure width
  \rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}[c][\textwidth][c]{\wd0}
    \usebox0
    \captionof{figure}{Figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption figure caption.}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{figure*}

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve.

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve.

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve.

\end{document}
```