# Placement of sideways figure

Tags: sidewaysfigure, figure-placement, sidewaysfigurepage

I have a figure which is wide and short. I am adding this to a paper in sideways format. It shows in one page which is ok. However, the placement does not look good.
It is shown as the red figure (a). I want it to be centered also in horizontally as shown in option b, green figure on the attached image.

I hope someone can help me to fix this?
Kind Regards,
Ferda

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=1\textheight,keepaspectratio]{figure.pdf}%
\caption{mycaption}
\label{mylabel}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (MWE) of your current code.

Comment: Are you in two column mode?  In any case, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399557/place-a-sidewaysfigure-correctly-in-a-two-column-document

Comment: No, I am not in two column mode..

Comment: You can try adjusting the placement of your figure by adding \hspace{} before the \includegraphics. Maybe it works: \begin{sidewaysfigure}[htb]
\centering
\hspace{1cm} % adjust this value to center your figure horizontally
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=1\textheight,keepaspectratio]{figure.pdf}%
\caption{mycaption}
\label{mylabel}
\end{sidewaysfigure}